# Javadocs - @param name not found

Tags: java, parameters, constructor, javadoc

I am trying to document one of my classes, but I keep getting the same error, and I don't understand why or how I can solve it.

Here is the relevant part of the code :

```
/** Set the health. 
    @param health The health of the enemy */
    public void setHealth(float health) {
        this.health = maximum_health;
    }

    /** initialising */
    public void initialise() {
        setName("NONE");
    }

    /** Constructor for the base enemy
    @param name The name of the enemy
    @param health The health of the enemy */
    public BaseEnemy(String name) { 
        initialise();
        setName(name);
        setHealth(health);
        }
```

The error I get when I document is the following :

```
Generating code/classes/docs/baseDoc/com/ama747/enemies/BaseEnemy.html...
code/src/BaseEnemy/BaseEnemy.java:27: error: @param name not found
    @param health The health of the enemy */
```

My question is the following : What's causing my error and how do I solve it ?

Comment: Probably the fact that the `BaseEnemy` constructor has no `health` param contrary to what the javadoc reports

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It says the problem correctly. You don't have a parameter called 'health' in your constructor.

Comment: What would I need to add then ?

Comment: please remove the javadoc line '@param health The health of the enemy' in your constructor.

Answer (score 3):

This is a formatting issue :

```
/**
 * 
 * @param health he health of the enemy
 */
public void setHealth(float health) {
    this.health = maximum_health;
}
```

Comment: Changing the way I type my comment doesn't seem to change anything

Comment: and don't forget the assumptions above that the constructor has no parameter named health

Answer (score 0):

As @мυѕτавєւмo points out, it seems a formatting issue.
Javadocs comments must start with /** and must end with */, with extra lines starting with *. It is mandatory, according to javadoc documentation:

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/index-137868.html

> The special comments in the Java source code that are delimited by the /** ... */ delimiters. These comments are processed by the Javadoc tool to generate the API docs.

In your initial example, those rules were not complied.